# AVAudioPlayer change sound tempo?

Tags: iphone, ios, avaudioplayer

I am making a rhythm game. I need to play a sound with different tempo. In other words e.g. if I have [AVAudioPlayer play] 8 times in 2 seconds.

Comment: I am using Finch. It can change pitch easily. But I need to change tempo. Looking setDuration method? Any one knows how to use setDuration in Finch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've used Pitch Shifting using the Fourier Transform – Source Code

http://www.dspdimension.com/download/

Comment: Hi does this lib can modify tempo without change the pitch ? (would not alter the note)

Answer (score 3):

Check out the

```
enableRate
```

and

```
rate
```

property on the AVAudioPlayer Class. After you create the audioplayer, but before you play, set

```
audioPlayer.enableRate=YES;
```

then after you play, set rate to a number above or below 1.0 to speed up or slow down the track. For music, less than 0.8 or more than 1.2 starts to sound bad, but for a few BMP up or down, it will easily do the trick.

Note that play sets the rate to 1 and stop sets the rate to 0, so be sure to set the desired rate after playing.